# Linux bash shell script sort lines

Tags: linux, shell

I have a File with following lines:

```
[172.16.50.134] 62825  
"/root/blz.txt" 62825  
[172.16.50.133] 62933  
"/home/Log/mail.log" 62933  
"/home/Log/log.txt" 62933  
[172.16.50.138] 67888  
"/home/Log/test.txt" 67888
```

but I need following Format:

```
[172.16.50.134] "/root/blz.txt"  
[172.16.50.133] "/home/Log/mail.log"   
[172.16.50.133] "/home/Log/log.txt"   
[172.16.50.138] "/home/Log/test.txt"
```

How can i do this with a Linux Shell Script ?
 Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. As @BrianAgnew said, you should show what you have done already and what you know. Thanks

Comment: look this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Note that if your original input wasn't representative of your *actual* question, but an answer that's correct for the question *as it was actually asked* is given, you should accept that answer and ask a new question. (Edits that change a question's meaning, as opposed to clarifying content already present, are welcome up to and until the point when an answer is given).

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0;}/^\[/{printf "%s %s ",$1,$2; a=0; b=$1; c=$2; next;}{if(a==0) {print $1; a=1} else {print b,c,$1}}' filename
```

Comment: Hello tso, thank you. It work perfect. But i have changed the input file.The lines with the IP has after the IP a User example [172.16.50.134] root 62825. And the output [172.16.50.134] root "/root/blz.txt"  I have tried but it doesn't work. Can you help  again ?